# Integrate Bootstrap on .liquid ( shopify )

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, liquid, liquid-layout

In shopify theme, I want to integrate following bootstrap link on `theme.liquid` file.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

How can i integrate bootstrap on my theme?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want to load everything so it works, add this code in the head of **Admin > Themes > Template Editor > theme.liquid**

Make sure to paste the code in-between the `<head> </head>` tags.

you can try to load them as the snippet bellow  :

```
{{ '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js' | script_tag }}
{{ '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
```

Comment: Shopify moved the path to get to this theme.liquid. It's now under Sales Channels>Themes then the user needs to select Actions and then edit code. theme.liquid is in the Layout group.

Answer (score 1):

It is a better practice to have your theme feed off CDN links, but also have it resort to a local bootstrap copy just in the case the CDN server is down.

Comment: How would you recommend doing that in Shopify? (the local copy)

Comment: Same way! You declare bootstrap library CDN links within your project. You should also create local files for these bootstrap CDNs separately and refer to them from your local repo. Make sure not to run the local repo unless the CDNs cannot be accessible. You can do this using JS.